# Is there some app that allows me to answer phone calls with my computer?

Tags: calls

Is there an app that allows me to answer phone calls with my computer? Sometimes it's uncomfortable to receive phone calls with the headset of my smartphone, it would be nice to talk when receiving a phone call through my computer headset which is way more comfortable.

**Note:** No, there isn't a comfortable headset in the near markets.

Comment: Is Google Voice available in your area? (That's what I use to answer phone calls on my computer.)

Comment: There is at least one. See [this post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=36294790&postcount=8) on XDA developers for the Play store link and some extra tweaks the post author needed to perform.

Comment: Yes. But I want to use my cellphone service for the call.